# How to highlight active workspace switcher's workspace name?

Tags: 11.10, workspaces, gnome-classic

I am using Gnome Classic in 11.10 and when I select a particular workspace it does not highlight it, so I do not know on which workspace I am unless I remember which one I clicked.

I have no problems operating the switcher, it is just the highlighting issue purely for cosmetics and ease of use.

How can I get the highlight active workspace switcher's workspace name?

Comment: To best figure this out, can you tell us how exactly you were able to get gnome 3 working in 11.10? My current theory would be driver incompatability with Unity 3d or perhaps 2d.

Answer (score 2):

To get gnome classic I followed something like this http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-make-ubuntu-11-10-look-and-feel-like-gnome-2/

OK I fixed it, I installed gnome-tweak-tool and in the themes option switched to a theme (Adwaita) that has a similar look to ambiance (which is the one I like) and with that theme the workspace highlighting works.